# UI (angular) Bootstrap datepicker component popup above controll

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

Is there a way to make the [UI Bootstrap datepicker popup](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) component appear above the controll instead of under?